# Facebook Javascript SDK: Reading from the stream using FQL

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

I am using this very simple query as part of Javascript to read from the stream using FB API. Somehow it does not return any data. I am able to read from the user table, is the way to access the stream table any different ?

```
function fqlFeed(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                 var query1 = FB.Data.query("SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() ");

                 query1.wait(function(rows1) {
                     alert('Name is ' + rows1[0].message);
                   document.getElementById('name1').innerHTML =
                     'Your name: ' + rows1[0].message + "<br />" ;                         

                 });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The FB.Data.query API was deprecated, as announced in today's Operation Developer Love [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/). I would suggest trying to use [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to run your query. To do this, simply follow the instructions for running an old-style REST API, but use `fql.query` for the method name, and pass in a `query` parameter with your query in it.

Comment: Thanks. I still seem to have issues with this. Other tables seem to work, only stream has an issue. Is there a need to pass an access token ?

Comment: Generally, yes, if you want to read non-public posts for a user. Check out the documentation for the stream table for the details - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Comment: the documentation indicates that even for public posts the acess token is required, do you have any sample code or working example of accessing data from the stream

Comment: You can use the JS SDK's FB.login method to make sure the SDK has an access token, then you can use FB.api({method: "fql.query", query: "SELECT..."},callback) to do the actual query.